# Referencing enum value held inside of a require module from underscore template

Tags: javascript, requirejs, underscore.js

I have an enum called repeatButtonState.

```
//  repeatButtonState.js:
define({
    DISABLED: 0,
    REPEAT_VIDEO_ENABLED: 1,
    REPEAT_STREAM_ENABLED: 2
});
```

I am now rendering repeatButton using underscore's templating engine:

```
<script type="text/template" id="repeatButtonTemplate">

    <% if(state === RepeatButtonState.REPEAT_STREAM_ENABLED) { %>

        <svg class="pressed repeatButtonSvgIcon" width="16" height="16" >
            <g transform="scale(0.57,0.57)" fill="#666" stroke="none">
                <path d="M24.249,15.499C24.24,20.331,20.331,24.240000000000002,15.498999999999999,24.249000000000002C12.983999999999998,24.249000000000002,10.730999999999998,23.185000000000002,9.133999999999999,21.486000000000004L11.201999999999998,20.044000000000004L3.3009999999999984,16.341000000000005L4.044999999999998,25.035000000000004L6.237999999999998,23.506000000000004C8.481999999999998,26.100000000000005,11.799999999999997,27.748000000000005,15.497999999999998,27.748000000000005C22.264999999999997,27.748000000000005,27.747,22.266000000000005,27.747,15.499000000000004H24.249ZM15.499,6.75C18.015,6.75,20.268,7.8149999999999995,21.866,9.514L19.798,10.956999999999999L27.698999999999998,14.658L26.953,5.965L24.761,7.494C22.516,4.9,19.198999999999998,3.2489999999999997,15.498999999999999,3.2489999999999997C8.734,3.25,3.25,8.734,3.249,15.499H6.75C6.758,10.668,10.668,6.758,15.499,6.75Z" stroke-width="3" stroke-linejoin="round">    
                </path>
                <path d="M24.249,15.499C24.24,20.331,20.331,24.240000000000002,15.498999999999999,24.249000000000002C12.983999999999998,24.249000000000002,10.730999999999998,23.185000000000002,9.133999999999999,21.486000000000004L11.201999999999998,20.044000000000004L3.3009999999999984,16.341000000000005L4.044999999999998,25.035000000000004L6.237999999999998,23.506000000000004C8.481999999999998,26.100000000000005,11.799999999999997,27.748000000000005,15.497999999999998,27.748000000000005C22.264999999999997,27.748000000000005,27.747,22.266000000000005,27.747,15.499000000000004H24.249ZM15.499,6.75C18.015,6.75,20.268,7.8149999999999995,21.866,9.514L19.798,10.956999999999999L27.698999999999998,14.658L26.953,5.965L24.761,7.494C22.516,4.9,19.198999999999998,3.2489999999999997,15.498999999999999,3.2489999999999997C8.734,3.25,3.25,8.734,3.249,15.499H6.75C6.758,10.668,10.668,6.758,15.499,6.75Z"></path>
            </g>
        </svg>

    <% } else { %>

        <svg class="repeatButtonSvgIcon <%- state === RepeatButtonState.REPEAT_VIDEO_ENABLED ? 'pressed' : '' %>" width="16" height="16">
            <g transform="scale(0.57,0.57)" fill="#666" stroke="none">
                <path d="M24.083,15.5C24.073999999999998,20.239,20.238999999999997,24.073999999999998,15.499999999999998,24.083C10.758999999999999,24.073999999999998,6.922999999999998,20.238999999999997,6.914999999999997,15.499999999999998C6.922999999999997,10.758999999999999,10.758999999999997,6.922999999999998,15.499999999999998,6.914999999999997C17.412999999999997,6.914999999999997,19.165,7.543999999999997,20.589999999999996,8.600999999999997L18.807999999999996,10.383999999999997L27.236999999999995,12.639999999999997L24.976999999999997,4.212999999999997L23.086999999999996,6.102999999999997C21.014999999999997,4.425999999999997,18.369999999999997,3.414999999999997,15.499999999999996,3.414999999999997C8.826,3.418,3.418,8.826,3.416,15.5C3.418,22.175,8.826,27.583,15.5,27.583S27.583,22.175,27.583,15.5H24.083Z" stroke-width="3" stroke-linejoin="round">
                </path>
                <path d="M24.083,15.5C24.073999999999998,20.239,20.238999999999997,24.073999999999998,15.499999999999998,24.083C10.758999999999999,24.073999999999998,6.922999999999998,20.238999999999997,6.914999999999997,15.499999999999998C6.922999999999997,10.758999999999999,10.758999999999997,6.922999999999998,15.499999999999998,6.914999999999997C17.412999999999997,6.914999999999997,19.165,7.543999999999997,20.589999999999996,8.600999999999997L18.807999999999996,10.383999999999997L27.236999999999995,12.639999999999997L24.976999999999997,4.212999999999997L23.086999999999996,6.102999999999997C21.014999999999997,4.425999999999997,18.369999999999997,3.414999999999997,15.499999999999996,3.414999999999997C8.826,3.418,3.418,8.826,3.416,15.5C3.418,22.175,8.826,27.583,15.5,27.583S27.583,22.175,27.583,15.5H24.083Z">
                </path>
            </g>
        </svg> 

    <% } %>

</script>
```

This throws an error because RepeatButtonState is undefined. Is it possible to reference RepeatButtonState from within a template?

Here is my RepeatButtonView which renders the template:

```
define([
    'repeatButtonState'
], function (RepeatButtonState) {
    'use strict';

    var RepeatButtonView = Backbone.View.extend({
        className: 'repeatButton button',

        template: _.template($('#repeatButtonTemplate').html()),

        events: {
            'click': 'toggleRepeat'
        },

        disabledTitle: chrome.i18n.getMessage("repeatDisabled"),
        repeatVideoEnabledTitle: chrome.i18n.getMessage("repeatVideoEnabled"),
        repeatPlaylistEnabledTitle: chrome.i18n.getMessage("repeatPlaylistEnabled"),

        render: function () {
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));

            switch(this.model.get('state')) {
                case RepeatButtonState.DISABLED:
                    this.$el.attr('title', this.disabledTitle);
                    break;
                case RepeatButtonState.REPEAT_VIDEO_ENABLED:
                    this.$el.attr('title', this.repeatVideoEnabledTitle);
                    break;
                case RepeatButtonState.REPEAT_STREAM_ENABLED:
                    this.$el.attr('title', this.repeatPlaylistEnabledTitle);
                    break;
                default:
                    console.error("Unhandled repeatButtonState:", this.model.get('state'));
                    break;
            }

            return this;
        },

        initialize: function () {
            this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:state', this.render);
        },

        toggleRepeat: function () {
            this.model.toggleRepeat();
        }
    });

    return RepeatButtonView;
});
```

I was previously hiding/showing elements based on RepeatButtonState inside of render, but I thought it would be better to just splash a bit of logic into the template.

Comment: How are you rendering the template?

Comment: I'll add that in. One sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mix RepeatButtonState into your model. Underscore templates don't use function scope, they rely on the 'with' statement for variable scoping. To get your template to render with your enum, you need to do something like this:

```
this.$el.html(this.template(
    _.extend(this.model.toJSON(), { 
        'RepeatButtonState': RepeatButtonState 
    })
));
```